# Javascript Unnecessarily Compact Array Operations

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, for my own knowledge, and because I love looking at things from a different perspective...
I have the following bite of Javascript code, which for this problem's intents and purposes will only ever receive strings formatted like this: "wordone wordtwo":

```
 function inName(inputName) {
    return inputName.split(" ")[1].toUpperCase();
 }
```

However, this only returns half of what I want ("WORDTWO"). I desire to return the original string with a single change: the space-separated second word returned through the toUpperCase(); and then re-concatenated to the untouched first word.
I also want to unnecessarily run all of the operations on the return line. My brain says this is possible, given how as the compiler reads the line from left to right and makes adjustments to the available member functions based on what has resolved. Also everything in Javascript is an object, correct?
Help me out for my own curiosity's sake, or bash me over the head with my own misconceptions.
Here is a solved version of the above question using 'normal' statements:

```
 function inName(inputName) {
    var nameArray=inputName.split(" ");
    nameArray[1]=nameArray[1].toUpperCase();
    return nameArray.join(" ");
 }
```

Comment: While this is possible using a regular expression, you current method is the most readable and that's always the best. However I would prefer to rename variables, e.g. `words` instead of `nameArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option which avoids the regular expression:

```
function inName(inputName) {
    return inputName.split(' ').map(function(v,i){return i?v.toUpperCase():v;}).join(' ');
}
```

This does the same split as the original code, then maps the parts to a function which returns the value at index 0 unchanged but the value at index 1 in upper case. Then the two results are joined back together with a space.

As others have said, a longer, clearer version is better in practice than trying to come up with a clever one-liner. Defining a function inside the return statement feels like cheating anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One line with `substr`, `indexOf` and a variable *on the fly* ;-)

```
function inName(inputName) {
 return inputName.substr(0, (index = inputName.indexOf(' '))) + inputName.substr(index).toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this almost seems like it belongs on Code Golf, but here's my take:

```
function inName(inputName) {
    return inputName.replace(/ .*/,function(m) {return m.toUpperCase();});
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm not a Stack Overflow user, really, so I do apologize if my question does not belong here.

Comment: @PaulPorter Code Golf is for discussing how to write unnecessarily compact or obfuscated code. Normal coding doesn't have arbitrary requirements that everything fit on one line.

Comment: Sounds like a place I should go visit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Here is my take on the problem

```
function justDoIt(str){
    return [str = str.split(" ") , str.pop().toUpperCase()].join(" ");
}
```

Creates a new array, str is split and reassigned as an array, and the first item of the new array, then the second new array item pops the last word, makes it uppercase, puts it into the new array. Then joins the array `[["wordOne"],"WORDTWO"].join(" ")`